# Cannot unzip the file located on remote centos machine using Ansible

Tags: unzip, ansible

```
- name: Unzip the Elasticsearch file
  unarchive: src=/root/elasticsearch-1.4.0.tar.gz dest=/tmp/


TASK [Unzip the Elasticsearch file]     
*******************************************
fatal: [54.173.94.235]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! file or module does not exist: /root/elasticsearch-1.4.0.tar.gz"}
```

Is it consider the local file? ...I am running file on my local machine to unzip file on the remote machine. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You would need to post related part of the playbook to get useful answer.

Comment: @marbu: posted playbook

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default, Ansible copies the file (src) from control machine to the remote machine and unarchives it. If you do not want Ansible to copy the file, set `copy=no` in your task.

The value of `copy` is `yes` by default, so Ansible will try to look for `src` file in the local machine if you do not set `copy=no`

```
unarchive: src=/root/elasticsearch-1.4.0.tar.gz dest=/tmp/ copy=no
```

[Ansible - Unarchive](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html)

> **Copy**
>
> If true, the file is copied from local 'master' to the target machine,
>   otherwise, the plugin will look for src archive at the target machine.

Comment: I want to unzip the folder on the remote machine using ansible script. i am running my script on my local machine and apply those changes to the remote centos machine. Copy will not work in those case. What would be the alternative ?

Comment: Where is the archive file? on the local machine or on remote machine?

Comment: It is on the remote machine and want to unzip it on the remote machine in a 'tmp' folder

Comment: Then the archive file does not exist on the remote machine: `ERROR! file or module does not exist: /root/elasticsearch-1.4.0.tar.gz`

Comment: It is...It is already there on the remote machine. When I write 'src' it will look for the file on the local machine, that I don't wanna do. How can I let ansible know that file is already there and you just need to unzip it on the remote machine itself ?

Comment: set `copy=no`

`unarchive: src=/root/elasticsearch-1.4.0.tar.gz dest=/tmp/ copy=no`

Comment: Note that as of right now the docs say that `copy` is deprecated and that you should use `remote_src` instead. This is a lie that's only true if you're running ansible from master. `remote_src` is not yet released, so if you're baffled why it's not working, it's because it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

add option "remote_src: yes" to unarchive module declaration

you can find it over here ""http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/unarchive_module.html

Comment: This is a better answer. `copy` has been deprecated.